# Monte-Carlo Weather Simulation

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo

I have a trained model that predicts some interesting things (like energy usage) based on the weather (temperature, humidity, etc.). I would like to run a monte carlo on the model and get a probability distribution for the coming years. I could do something like look at the average temperature (humidity, etc) every day and perturb it, but that feels like a fair amount of work, and I am wondering if there are more standard ways to do this. Maybe there are public domain weather models out there that will generate multiple runs of speculative weather?

Any and all ideas welcome...

Comment: How many supercomputers do you have networked? In all seriousness, weather during a course of years is no longer called "weather": it is called *climate*.  Whose climate change model are you going to pick?

Comment: I am not interested in an accurate prediction, and sorry if I gave that impression. I am interested in getting some kind of probability distribution that I can base economic decisions on. And I can bring a fair amount of computation resources to bear on this problem if need be, but I don't anticipate needing that.

Comment: But if you have no interest in whether that probability distribution is accurate, the possibilities are endless: generate any distribution you like!  In all seriousness, it would be helpful to know (in a quantitative sense) just what level of accuracy you need.

Comment: I would like to do monte carlo runs, i.e. generate a random set of weather that is a reasonalbe guess of what could occur. Probably by sampling past weather. And then do it again. And again. Until I get a probability distribution of how much energy usage my model is predicting. I can use sampling statistics to get confidence intervals. 

However what I want to know is if there is a more standard way of doing this, perhaps using open source weather pediciton packages. It seems not...

Comment: I am not stymied, and I know a way to proceed which is reasonable, and can be made more so with more work. I am just looking for alternate suggestions. Due diligence so to say.